# android, lastModified() is 1.1.1970

Tags: android, file, last-modified

I want to get the lastModified() to compare the date.
I do this:

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(getFilesDir()+File.separator + "openliga.txt");
file.write(changeObj.toString());
file.flush();
file.close();
```

I Check via DDMS and the file browser, the file exist!

then

```
// Check the Time Stamp of the internal File
File intfile = new File(getFilesDir()+File.separator + "openliga.txt");

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String dateInt = sdf.format(intfile.lastModified());

Log.e("LastMod", String.valueOf(dateInt));
```

tells me:

```
Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970
```

Is it possible, that android do not find the file? Why?

Comment: It does look like it can't find the file. `Returns the time when this file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, midnight. Returns 0 if the file does not exist.`

Answer (score 1):

You cant directly format `intfile.lastModified()` as date because `intfile.lastModified()` is time in milli. So need to add in Date and then format date as you want.

**Edit:** 
Also you need to check if file exist or not.

Try this

```
if (intfile.exists()) {

   long lastmodified = intfile.lastModified();
   Date date = new Date();
   date.setTime(lastmodified);
   SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

   String dateInt = postFormater.format(date);
}
```